# I cannot seem to find out if this webservice is getting the JSON object sent from Android

Tags: android, json, web-services, httpresponse

I have a android application which sends JSON information to a webservice for it to validate the information. I am using Kate as an editor for the webservice. The concept of JSON and php webservices is new to me. I normally code in java.

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    String userID = "";

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(loginURI);
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams,10000);

    try {

        jsonObject.put("username", username);
        Log.i("username", jsonObject.toString());
        jsonObject.put("password", password);
        Log.i("password", jsonObject.toString());

        StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
        stringEntity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            userID = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
            Log.i("Read from server", userID);
         }


    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.e("Login_Issue", e.toString());
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }


    return userID;
}
```

I found the StringEntity code online and thought it will work. I do not understand the purpose of the StringEntity for the HttpPost.

This is my webservice written in php.

```
include('dbconnect.php'); 

$tablename = 'users';

//username and password sent from android
$username=$_POST['myusername'];
$password=$_POST['mypassword'];

//protecting mysql injection
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

#$array = array($username,$password);
$sql = "SELECT first_name FROM $tablename WHERE u_username='$username' AND    u_password=MD5('$password')"; 
//Querying the database
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if(!$result){
   die(mysql_error();
}


//If found, number of rows must be 1
if((mysql_num_rows($result))==1){

//creating session
session_register("$username");
session_register("$password");

print true;
}else{
print false;
}

mysql_close();
```

I am not quite sure if the 'username' and the 'password' is being sent correctly from the android app to the webservice. How can I verify this? And is the webservice and the java code well-written to send the information in JSON?

When I go the webservice on the browser, I get the following error:
    Parse error: parse error in E:\wamp\www\mobile.dcl.mu\webserver\login.php on line 24

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can create jsonarray on server side and get that array from client side in order to see if the pass and username retrieved correctly. It is just the same process like you did on sending json to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to bite off too much. It should be, like, 6 different questions (or just pay someone to write the scripts for you, or spend some time learning the technologies in isolation). Two first things to fix:

- **fix the parse error!** it is as if you had a Java source that does not compile. The error is that you forgot the closing paren after `die (mysql_error();`
- **no, it will not work anyway.** You send the data in the body as `application/json`, and you try to read it as url-encoded form. Decide which you want, ask for help on that.
- remove the stripslashes. It does not add any security and will cause errors if anyone is using a slash in her password. Unless you have magic_quotes on, which you should not.

Since you made the three very basic mistakes so early, I am practically sure that there is much, much more to fix. Other than rewriting the whole thing for you or sending some general links on PHP programming and web application programming - I see no more way to help you. If you manage to split the problem, test things in isolation and ask more questions, there might be hope.

**UPDATE**

If you decide to standardize around JSON, the general pattern in your PHP files will be:

```
// get the body of the HTTP request (that's the "http entity")
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');

// translate JSON into ordinary PHP array:
$entity = json_decode($test, true);

// Now you can read parts of it as if you read an array;
// the data may be nested and will mirror exactly your JSONObject:

$username=$entity['myusername'];
$password=$entity['mypassword'];
```

[yes, that's me begging for an upvote :-)]

[and I think there is more problems in your Java code, but one thing at a time]

Comment: That was quite harsh but thank you for pointing out my mistakes. I am new at web development and there is a lot to learn and I'm aware of this. I will keep your points in mind for the future. Thanks

Comment: What do you suggest I use for sending the data? application/json or url-encoded form?

Comment: @mokko211: well, maybe harsh, but I did spend some time finding the parse error (and so on). My answer is not a rant, I tried to actually help you with three solutions that I could identify in the couple of minutes I had to spare. There is probably much more, but unless you apply what I have already written, you will not know what to do next.

Comment: @mokko211: now THIS is an answerable question :-) The answer is: if you plan on sending complicated structures, go with JSON. If you are fine with flat hashes indexed by strings, use ordinary parameters.